# FileWriter not creating new file if it does not exist

Tags: java, android, file, filewriter

Code :

```
f = new FileWriter(context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/abc.txt", true);
```

Write Permissions are given. Checked in settings.
While debugging, I was getting error on the line above.

Error : FileNotFoundException

Comment: You do not need any permission for getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: @blackapps Ok. But then then what is the problem. I have been stuck here for 2 days now.

Comment: Try using the `FileWriter(File)` constructor if the file does not exist. Also, please do not use string concatenation to assemble filesystem paths. So, use `new FileWriter(new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "abc.txt"))`.